# Modern Batch Processing in Linux

Tags: linux, batch-file

What tools, languages, and infrastructure do you use for do batch processing in Linux?

I am looking for something that facilitate the tasks of:

- Process files
- Log
- Validation
- Job Controlling (start,strop,reestart a process)
- Mysql Connection

Thanks for any help!

Comment: None of the responders seem to understand what batch processing is, even though it is quite simple. In essence, batch processing is the sequential execution of a queue of non-interactive workloads (programs, scripts). In the olden days, when CPU time was a scarce resource, it was often the only way you could get your computing done. There is, of course, no native batch processing facility in Linux (or Unix), since Unix evolved as a time-sharing system. More information here: http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/zos/basics/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.zos.zconcepts/zconc_whatisbatch.htm

Comment: See [Batch Processing with one task at a time](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/559304/batch-processing-with-one-task-at-a-time) as a possible frontend application.

Answer (score 1):

cron jobs are what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Bash scripts are still used for almost everything. It really depends on what the job is at hand. I tend to resort to Perl for heavy text processing with its wonderful regex support and short syntax for instant hackability. I might use Python if I want to do something more complex that will need to be maintained over time. It really depends. But for the majority of "batch scripting" Bash scripts are used.

Answer (score 1):

Tools languages infrastructure? `Vim`, `bash`, `cron`. Unless I misunderstand your question. For MySQL type tasks I use `perl` or `python`.

Answer (score 1):

We use [Python](http://www.python.org).

Process files - the `os` module does some of this.

Log - the `logging` module.

Validation - no idea what this means.

Job Controlling (start,strop,reestart a process) - this is complex, ambitious and difficult to define.  Some folks use commercial products for this because of the potential auditability issues.  Control/M, Tivoli, etc., are good solutions.  However, you can build some of this using `at` and `cron`.

Mysql Connection - This is done via `MySQLdb` add-on.

Answer (score 0):

If we're talking about an enterprise implementation, I recommend [Load Sharing Facility](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Platform_LSF).  This is a system that distributes jobs across a cluster of machines.  It allows for queueing of jobs; pausing and stopping jobs; and gives plenty of statistics.  You can have one or a few machines be "logon" machines where people submit jobs from and several machines that run the jobs full time.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Pentaho Data Integration?

With PDI you can just draw flowcharts instead of programming...  It's awesome!

Just kidding.

Answer (score 0):

Bash is your friend. I would also suggest using Python but thats a bit more preference in my opinion. Also if this is something that needs to be accessed or maintained by slightly less ummmm competent individuals you can create an Interface easily using PHP.